# The role of the 'main.cpp' in a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt project we generally find a `project.pro` file, the `main.cpp` and several header, source and `*.ui` files, containing all the resources to breathe life and function into the application/project.
If there is more to it than *"press the button to show 'Hello, world!'"*, there might be directories for storing data and configuration files, etc.

My question is (in spite of the fact that an exact answer depends on the specific situation):

**What is the general role of the main.cpp in a Qt project (Qt Widgets Application)?**

---

To make clear what I mean:

1. Is the `main.cpp`'s only purpose to kick off the application?
2. If not, what are typical tasks to be performed by the `main.cpp`?
3. Speaking of config files - consider the application has a main form which has (and maybe other classes/dialogs instantiated by the main form as well) to know about some configuration data retrieved from a file. Would the initialization happen in the `main.cpp` or in the `MainForm`. In short: *"Setting things up..."* should be placed where (in the light of the current question)?
4. Whatever you feel like saying...

Comment: The nomenclature is merely convention and most of times nothing more than an indication that the file contains the main entry point of your program, i.e. a function with a signature `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` (not sure if other signature are permitted by the standard). When you use the project wizard of, say, Qt Creator, and provided you choose to let it create a Qt Project, it will generate the basic structure of your program, including a `main.cpp`, which holds said entry point and other stuff, among which you'll find the `.pro` file and other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Note: A complete answer should incorporate @thokra's comment, which is to say that `main.cpp` is a filename and the appearance of the program entry point in a file with that name is only convention.  But it's a fairly well-adhered to convention in Qt programs and C++ in general to try and put the program's entry point in a file with that name.)*

One category would be registration of global hooks and settings.  Think about things like [qInstallMessageHandler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler), or [QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings).

Initialization of any *non-Qt* libraries that your app wants to take for granted would be another area.

If your program has a main window object that's only created and destroyed one time, it might seem equally suitable to put the "run once" code in its constructor/destructor.  But ask yourself exactly what is it about your app that only lets it have one main window.  Why wouldn't it be able to have two in the same process?  Even if that's not part of the requirement today, it can suggest an architectural boundary.

I'll mention from personal experience that if you try making a class derived from QApplication, and then put your global run-once-code in the constructor and destructor of that derived class, that is trickier than it sounds *(especially if you spawn threads and make widgets in that constructor)*.  So I don't think in most scenarios you should derive from QApplication.  I stuck with it because I was making an application *framework*...but avoid that and your run-once code goes in the main.cpp.

Comment: You confirm my own assumptions that the main should maybe contain what is absolutely necessary to "run" the application at all and all "run-once" code *if* there is no MainForm that will be instantiated only once. In my specific project, I have only one MainForm (called `Home`), which you could consider the user's command center from where he performs all operations. If you close it, you close the application. Since I divided my project into `logic` and `gui`, preparations concerning the `logic` could be located in the main, preparations for `gui`, such as reading user settings [...]

Comment: [...] from a config file, etc. would reside with `Home`...
(Note that the `Home` object will never be destroyed during a run time). Do you "agree" to my ideas? (Actually, I have a `Settings` class (singleton) which takes care of that stuff, I just need to decide whether to engage it in `main.cpp` or `Home`...)

Comment: @LCsa Hmm, well don't go coming up with objects with names like `Universe` and then because you don't want to have global variables you wind up passing `Universe` to every function.  You just reinvented globals and added a layer of hassle. But consider: if I came to your codebase and wanted to write a non-GUI app that is a settings tweaker, how many changes would I have to make? Why would reading the settings *require* a window creation? Just guidelines here, at the end of the day no programs are perfect, besides [Red](http://blog.hostilefork.com/why-rebol-red-parse-cool/) >:-P

Comment: Reading the settings, for instance, doesn't have a window, it's a class, working in the background, not visible for the user. But it has to be called (by `main.cpp`/`Home`) and used to make the interface look like when the user left it the last time, for example. There will be a window where the user can specify settings, though. This window and the class behind it will closely interact with the `Settings` class (or `Universe`, to quote you. :-P) If those settings affect the whole application many other classes will, for better or worse, have to access it, no? [...]

Comment: [...] However, you could still take my `logic` independently and perfectly use it as a console application or build an entirely new GUI for it...

Comment: @LCsa BTW you are aware of QSettings and [QMainWindow::saveState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState), right?  I can't answer a completely abstract question about how to distribute configuration data in a system other than to say that I find simplicity is critical.  And if you make it painless to quit a program and restart it with a new config then the program might be simpler to write and less unpredictable than if a subsystem captured a config state and didn't get adjusted to account for it.  Or you can just program in Haskell.  :-)

Comment: That's a nice tip, haven't heard of those yet. I'll take a look in. However, since I'm fairly new to the whole GUI programming stuff (I learned C++ as a physics student, not a software programmer... :-P) I don't want to use too many "black boxes" at once, but slowly build up  my personal tool box. Thus, for now I rather have conceptual questions than technical ones. Right now, I'm storing data to files and not to databases, I'm storing setting information in files and not in some QSettings class, do you know what I mean? Once, I'm through with what I'm dealing with right now, I'll expand [...]

Comment: [...] my set of tools and definitely find nicer solutions for several problems. Right now, I focusing on separating logic from GUI and keeping everything as simple and intuitive as possible... Thanks, for all your answers (now accepted). Eventually, I'd somehow like to present my applications to gather criticism.

Answer (score 3):

> *"1. Is the main.cpp's only purpose to kick off the application?"*

As from the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [standards definition][1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) the 1st section says:

> **3.6 Start and termination [basic.start]**
>   **3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]**
>   <sup>1</sup> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. It
>   is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function.
>   [ Note: *In a freestanding environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined; startup
>   contains the execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static storage duration;
>   termination contains the execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration.* —end note ]

A [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) application is still using C++, thus this constraint needs to be satisfied for any executable application.
So presumably: Yes, the `main()`'s only purpose is to kick off the application.

`MainForm` and `main()` aren't really strongly related, other than your configuration will generate a `main()` function instantiating and calling it. You can also have Qt projects, that don't have any `MainForm` instance at all (e.g. a just command line app).

Comment: This would support the version of putting the stuff into the `MainForm` and let the `main.cpp` just kick everything off...

Comment: @LCsa _"This would support the version ..."_ Of course! Totally depends on what the Qt Creator IDE provides for you when generating `main()` for a particular project type.